# Allow debugging with WCF fileless activation in .NET 4.0

Tags: wcf, configuration, .net-4.0

I have been testing out the new WCF fileless activation stuff in .net 4 that allows you to use config rather than having a physical svc file.

The relevant part of my web.config looks like this:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="Service1.svc" service="WcfService1.Service1" factory="WcfService1.UnityServiceHostFactory" />
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

This runs ok but if I add any breakpoints, they do not get hit. When using svc files, they have debug="true" in the markup but I do not know how to allow this when doing it through config.

Any ideas?

Comment: I cannot believe that nobody has answered this. Can I assume that it is a huge glaring omission in the rush to get WCF4 out of the door?

Comment: I had this same problem today, even though the VS asp.net host was running the debugger wasn't attached until I told the Solution to include the asp.net project in startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops. It seems as though I was mistaken. After being called on to something else for a while, I have revisited this code and it appears to be working normally. The debug flag in normal svc files doesn't actual do anything.